# Unsupported URL iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, http, url

I have a valid url and i get - unsupported url error. Can tell me somebody why?

As you can see there is http://

```
// http://fr.radiovaticana.va/news/2015/02/01/le_pape_fran%C3%A7ois_%C3%A0_sarajevo_le_6_juin_prochain/1121065

Error description=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x78f97920 {NSUnderlyingError=0x79f78bd0 "unsupported URL", NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
```

This is how i was trying to init the url :

Method 1 :

```
NSString *path=@"http://fr.radiovaticana.va/news/2015/02/01/le_pape_françois_à_sarajevo_le_6_juin_prochain/1121065";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSMutableURLRequest * request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Method 2 :

```
NSMutableURLRequest * request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fr.radiovaticana.va/news/2015/02/01/le_pape_françois_à_sarajevo_le_6_juin_prochain/1121065"]];
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

URL's can not contain characters that are not in the ASCII character-set, such characters must be escaped.

Use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` with the character-set `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet`

```
NSString *path = @"http://fr.radiovaticana.va/news/2015/02/01/le_pape_françois_à_sarajevo_le_6_juin_prochain/1121065";
NSString *escapedPath = [path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"escapedPath: %@", escapedPath);
```

Output:

```
escapedPath: http://fr.radiovaticana.va/news/2015/02/01/le_pape_fran%C3%A7ois_%C3%A0_sarajevo_le_6_juin_prochain/1121065\
```

See Character Set for URL Encoding [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet)

Comment: Sweet! Nice Answer

Comment: Great answer! (Testing to see if I also get an upvote for this comment)