# Error sending JSONArray parameter in url (iOS)

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, afnetworking-2, jsonkit

i need to convert an array into json and send it as a parameter in a url along with other parameters. I am using jsonKit for json conversion and AFNetworking for network communication.But it always gives exception in the json at the server.

Here is the code used for son conversion:

```
NSString *jsonData = [self.finalArray JSONString];
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",[jsonData UTF8String] ];
```

This data is finally send as a parameter in the url. 
code for network communication :

```
postData=[postData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSURL *requestUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",url,postData]];
NSURLRequest *request =[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestUrl];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
[operation start];
```

Also used following for escape characters:

> [postData stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

Error received :

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7d51e9a0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}}, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported URL iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267557/unsupported-url-ios)

Comment: already tried the solution there. But it still gives the same error. I think the problem lies in converting the array into JSON.

Comment: the problem is in your encoding place check once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you please point out the error.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use it like this

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/add-product.php", apiPrefix];

[manager POST:strURL parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
{
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictData options:0 error:&error]; // dictData is your dictionary
    NSAssert(jsonData, @"Failure building JSON: %@", error);

    NSDictionary *jsonHeaders = @{@"Content-Disposition" : @"form-data; name=\"data\""}; // data is your parameter name in which you have to pass the json

    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:jsonHeaders body:jsonData];
}

success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Hope this will help....

Comment: The answer would be much more useful if it explained how the answer provides a solution to the question.